# A tool to get window dimensions

Tags: software-recommendation, window, layout

I need a tool to get the width and height of an arbitrary window.

Ideally, that tool would deduct the size of the Ubuntu's menu bar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your own answer, I understand you are looking for a convenient GUI tool, so:

#### Small GUI tool to get both the net size and the *real* size of a window (dynamically updated)

As explained further below in "Explanation", both `wmctrl` and `xdotool` return a slightly incorrect windowsize.

[image]

The script (indicator) below will show both the "real" size and the net size of a window  in the panel.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import signal
import gi
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
import subprocess
from gi.repository import Gtk, AppIndicator3, GObject
import time
from threading import Thread


def get(cmd):
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

# ---
# uncomment either one of two the lines below; the first one will let the user
# pick a window *after* the indicator started, the second one will pick the 
# currently active window
# ---

window = get(["xdotool", "selectwindow"])
# window = get(["xdotool", "getactivewindow"])

class Indicator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = 'test123'
        iconpath = "unity-display-panel"
        self.indicator = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new(
            self.app, iconpath,
            AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.OTHER)
        self.indicator.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)       
        self.indicator.set_menu(self.create_menu())
        self.indicator.set_label(" ...Starting up", self.app)
        # the thread:
        self.update = Thread(target=self.show_seconds)
        # daemonize the thread to make the indicator stopable
        self.update.setDaemon(True)
        self.update.start()

    def create_menu(self):
        menu = Gtk.Menu()
        # separator
        menu_sep = Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem()
        menu.append(menu_sep)
        # quit
        item_quit = Gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
        item_quit.connect('activate', self.stop)
        menu.append(item_quit)
        menu.show_all()
        return menu

    def show_seconds(self):
        sizes1 = None
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            sizes2 = self.getsize(window)
            if sizes2 != sizes1:
                GObject.idle_add(
                    self.indicator.set_label,
                    sizes2, self.app,
                    priority=GObject.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                    )
            sizes1 = sizes2

    def getsize(self, window):
        try:
            nettsize = [int(n) for n in get([
                "xdotool", "getwindowgeometry", window
                ]).splitlines()[-1].split()[-1].split("x")]
        except AttributeError:
            subprocess.Popen(["notify-send", "Missing data", "window "+window+\
                              " does not exist\n(terminating)"])
            self.stop()
        else:
            add = [l for l in get(["xprop", "-id", window]).splitlines() if "FRAME" in l][0].split()
            add = [int(n.replace(",", "")) for n in add[-4:]]
            xadd = add[0]+add[1]; yadd = add[2]+add[3]
            totalsize = [str(s) for s in [nettsize[0]+add[0]+add[1], nettsize[1]+add[2]+add[3]]]
            displ_sizes = ["x".join(geo) for geo in [[str(s) for s in nettsize], totalsize]]
            string = " "+displ_sizes[0]+" / "+displ_sizes[1]
            return string+((25-len(string))*" ")

    def stop(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit()

Indicator()
GObject.threads_init()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
Gtk.main()
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs xdotool to be installed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `getwindowsize.py`
3. Test- run the script from a terminal window by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/getwindowsize.py
   ```
4. The script picks the ***focussed window*** to dynamically show the net windowsize (as in the output of both `wmctrl` and `xdotool`) and the *real* window size, including decorators etc.

   If you close the targeted window, the indicator shows a message:

   [image]
5. If all works fine, add it to a shortcut key: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/getwindowsize.py
   ```

### Explanation

#### The window size, as it is displayed by both wmctrl and xdotool

...is slightly incorrect

You mention:

***Ideally, that tool would deduct the size of the Ubuntu's menu bar***

The complete story is that both `wmctrl -lG` and `xdotool getwindowgeometry` return the size of the window without menu bar, or, as it is explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/579586/72216):

*What's happening is that wmctrl is returning the geometry of the window inside the decorations (i.e. not including the title bar and borders)*

#### How to get the correct, "real" size

To get the information correctly, we can run

```
xprop -id <window_id> | grep FRAME
```

This will output like:

```
_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 28, 0
```

Here we get the values we need to add to the window's size, as output from `wmctrl` and `xdotool`, to the left, right, top and bottom of the window.

In other words, in this case, if a `wmctrl` shows a size of 200x100, the *real* size is 200x128.

#### Note

As suggested by OP, the user can also pick a window *after* the indicator was started, by replacing:

```
window = get(["xdotool", "getactivewindow"])
```

by:

```
window = get(["xdotool", "selectwindow"])
```

In the script, either one of these lines can be uncommented.

Comment: Cheers @Jacob-vlijm, such a good answer!  
Just two things:  
1) I've replaced `getactivewindow` by `selectwindow`, so when the script is launched you choose with the cursor the window to get dimensions from. I find this behaviour much more convenient.  
2) [I've uploaded the code to paste ubuntu](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23678836/), so it's easier to set up:  Just download and save as getwindowsize.py

Comment: @Akronix Thanks! sounds like a great idea, would you mind if I edit it into the answer?

Comment: Sure @jacob-vljim. Feel free ;)

Answer (score 12):

You can use `wmctrl -lG` to get a list of all open windows, in a table with the format:

```
<window ID> <desktop ID> <x-coordinate> <y-coordinate> <width> <height> <client machine> <window title>
```

An example output could look like this:

```
$ wmctrl -lG
0x02a00002  0 -2020 -1180 1920 1080 MyHostName XdndCollectionWindowImp
0x02a00005  0 0    24   61   1056 MyHostName unity-launcher
0x02a00008  0 0    0    1920 24   MyHostName unity-panel
0x02a0000b  0 -1241 -728 1141 628  MyHostName unity-dash
0x02a0000c  0 -420 -300 320  200  MyHostName Hud
0x03a0000a  0 0    0    1920 1080 MyHostName Desktop
0x0400001d  0 61   24   1859 1056 MyHostName application development - A tool to get window dimensions - Ask Ubuntu - Mozilla Firefox
0x04200084  0 61   52   999  745  MyHostName Untitled Document 1 - gedit
```

Answer (score 9):

I found `xwininfo -all` from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14159/how-do-i-find-the-window-dimensions-and-position-accurately-including-decoration.

It does work but I'm still open to more convenient solutions => a real-time GUI tool.

Comment: I posted an answer, but didn't notice you've found `xwininfo` already. Perhaps you would be interested in the script I wrote - it uses `xwininfo` but with a GUI popup, please see it below.

Answer (score 2):

One could try:

```
xdotool search --name gnome-panel getwindowgeometry
```

Assuming gnome-panel is ubuntu's toolbar's process name, but who knows.

(may require a `sudo apt-get install xdotool`)

For an improvised GUI thing that one may want to further improve so to display just the bare essentials:

```
zenity --text-info --filename=<(xprop)
```

It will change the pointer to xprop's cross, then you click the window, and it will print xprop's info in a GTK dialog.

Answer (score 2):

#### xwininfo and its advantages

The big problem with `wmctrl` and `xdotool` is that those tools need to be installed - *they aren't on Ubuntu by default*. However, Ubuntu ships with `xwininfo`. It is a simple tool that provides information about user-selected window.

Simple usage would be to type in `xwininfo | awk '/Width/||/Height/'` (notice that `awk` is used for filtering the output) in terminal, and when your cursor changes to `x` select any GUI window you like and it will display its info. For example:

```
$ xwininfo | awk '/Width/||/Height/'                
  Width: 602
  Height: 398
```

So the advantages are:

- it is simple
- it is installed by default
- it's just text - nothing fancy and you can filter and tweak it as necessary

#### Taking xwininfo one step further - displaying properties of an active window

Of course if you have terminal open 24/7  like I do,  `xwininfo` is all you need. Some users might prefer having a keyboard shortcut. The script below (which is intended to be bound to a keyboard shortcut) allows you to display a graphical popup with information about your currently active window. As can be seen in the screenshot, it displays window title,width and height info.

[image]

Under the hood this doesn't do anything particularly spectacular. It uses information from `dbus` service and `xwininfo` and puts it into simple popup.  The source code is below. Remember, standard scripting rules apply: ensure it has executable permissions with `chmod +x` and when binding to keyboard shortcut you give full path to the script file as command.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash 

get_active_window()
{
    qdbus org.ayatana.bamf \
          /org/ayatana/bamf/matcher \
          org.ayatana.bamf.matcher.ActiveWindow
}

get_active_name()
{
    qdbus org.ayatana.bamf $1 \
          org.ayatana.bamf.view.Name
}

main()
{
    active_window=$(get_active_window)
    active_xid=$( awk -F '/' '{print $NF}' <<< "$active_window" )
    echo $active_xid
    active_title=$(get_active_name $active_window)
    dimensions=$(xwininfo -id "$active_xid" | awk '/Width/||/Height/')
    text="$active_title\n""$dimensions"
    zenity --info --text "$text" --width=200 --height=200
}

main $@
```

#### Using Unity's top panel indicator for information.

When writing my answer, I've realized  that this would be a very useful feature to incorporate into one of my existing projects - the Ayatana Indicator. This indicator allows showing whole range of information about GUI windows. Currently is still under active development. The geometry info feature has been added to the [github repository](https://github.com/SergKolo/ayatana-indicator) and is on the way into [my personal PPA](https://launchpad.net/~1047481448-2/+archive/ubuntu/sergkolo). And of course, it uses `xwininfo` although in slightly different manner.

[image]