# Window location in wmctrl

Tags: command-line, unity, wmctrl

I have open File Manager window in Ubuntu 16.06 (Unity). I want to make this window size to 400px x 400px and I want to locate top-left corner of this window in point (50, 20). To do this I run command:

```
wmctrl -r Home -e 0,50,20,400,400
```

After that I run command to check:

```
wmctrl -lG | grep Home
```

I get that response

```
0x02a00959  0 59   55   400  400  szymon-Vostro-14-5459 Home
```

We see that *Home* window has correct size, but it's located in point (59,55). Why?

Comment: Also look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/576604/what-causes-the-deviation-in-the-wmctrl-window-move-command

Comment: Is there any other solution for  **correctly** resizing i positioning windows in Compiz in bash?