# What is the Window Title Bar height in Pixel?

Tags: 19.10

I would like to get the height of the window title bar, for example of my browser or nautilus in pixel.

I am referring to the "dark part" in the screenshot, so the strip that holds the min,max,close buttons.

Where is this info stored and can I grep for it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From [What causes the deviation in the wmctrl window move command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576604/what-causes-the-deviation-in-the-wmctrl-window-move-command):

```bash
$ xprop | grep FRAME
_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 28, 0
```

Whenever you get a windows position and move it to that same position it shouldn't move on the screen but it does due to the height of the title bar. So in my case I would need to subtract 28 from the y-coordinate and move to that spot.

---

## Improving performance

You will find the command takes about 10 seconds to run:

```bash
$ time xprop | grep FRAME
_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 28, 0

real    0m9.989s
user    0m0.017s
sys     0m0.004s
```

This is extraordinary slow. To speed up the search pass a Window ID:

```bash
$ time xprop -id $(xdotool getactivewindow) | grep FRAME
_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 28, 0

real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.011s
sys     0m0.003s
```

Now it's only a hundredth of a second, faster than a blinking eye.