# Window positions messed up after docking

Tags: unity, workspaces, docking

I have a HD display on my laptop (Dell Latitude E7250) and a Full HD one on my docking station. When I dock my laptop the window positions often (yet not always) get messed up. Sometimes (some of) the windows get minimized and sometimes they switch to different workspaces, e.g. (1,1) to (1,6), usually staying on the same row.

Running Ubuntu 16.04 / Unity with 24 workspaces (6x4) (yes, I need that much).

Is there any way to fix this? Saving the layout somehow could help as I always have certain windows open on certain workspaces (e.g. IntelliJ Idea on (2,3).

Thanks.

Comment: Is this https://askubuntu.com/a/631467/72216 a possible solution?

Comment: Let me know if it works correctly in your situation, possibly it needs a little editing.

Comment: Works just fine

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the tweak tool, to fine tune and manage the workspace and window behavior

For 16.04 specifically:

Ubuntu unity-tweak-tool package
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/unity-tweak-tool

As Jacob Vlijin noted in the comments above, There is a related question and solution for Saving and restoring window positions here:

[Saving and restoring window positions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631392/saving-and-restoring-window-positions/631467#631467)

In Xubuntu 17.04 the 'Window Manager Tweaks' is the new interface.

Comment: What exactly should I do with it? Didn't find anything relevant really

Comment: Install it. and launch it, I can set-up a VM with 16.04 if more detail on steps is wanted?

Comment: I've had it installed for ages & think I used it to set up my workspace configuration in the first place.

Comment: If this is new behaviour it is likely related to a uniity update, the first trouble shooting step would be check current configuration.

Comment: I have had the same issue since I installed ubunty 16.04 on my machine

Comment: if the issue been resolved please acknowledge it, it takes time to review 4 month old inactive questions :)