# Command for restoring minimized windows

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, xdotool, wmctrl

Anyone knows the command to restore minimized windows? I need that command to configure Easystroke. For some reason, misc option is not working in that app so I need to enter the command manually. I'm using ubuntu 18.04 with gnome desktop.

Comment: Hi Dillon, could you remove your acceptance of Joshau's answer? If Im not mistaken, it is not correct and unmarking as accepted will encourage AU users to answer it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [a list of commands on this page](http://www.timelessguru.com/easystroke).

```
xdotool key --delay 50ms alt+space key n
```

should do the trick.

Comment: That is the listign for *minimize* (Minimize Command xdotool key --delay 50ms alt+space key n)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no Window Restore function built into Ubuntu (please correct me if Im wrong).

Here is what doesnt work:

Joshua's answer above using xdotool, and there isnt a Restore listed.

- in the script in this answer (https://askubuntu.com/a/631467/795299) wmctrl doesnt use a restore function
- none of the other answers from that question ([Saving and restoring window positions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/631392/saving-and-restoring-window-positions)) use and kind of restore function.

There is an xdotool use (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287363/why-xdotool-is-not-clicking-when-restoring-position) to use the mouse to click the restore button. This means it has to exist in the internals. Anyone know where that is?

Comment: to whomever voted to delete, please provide some kind of explanation, as you should be required to, and is generally good etiquette. I will only dispute facts, not opinion. Thanks