# Is there a way to Restore Window from maximized, if not where is the code for the window button that does this?

Tags: window, xdotool, wmctrl

This is not a duplicate of: [Command for restoring minimized windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034188/command-for-restoring-minimized-windows). (The answer is incorrect on that question and I don't know how to contact the mods to have it unmarked as accepted. I did find this discussion on what to do and have commented on the OP's question (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343324/how-to-flag-wrong-answers)).

Heres what Ive found out so far:

- In the accepted answer to the question above, using xdotool, the [link](http://www.timelessguru.com/easystroke), to EasyStroke commands, provided doesnt have a Restore function listed.
- In the script in this answer (https://askubuntu.com/a/631467/795299)
  wmctrl doesnt use a restore function none of the other answers from
  that question (Saving and restoring window positions) use and kind of
  restore function.
- There is an xdotool use
  (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287363/why-xdotool-is-not-clicking-when-restoring-position)
  to use the mouse to click the restore button. This means it has to
  exist in the internals. Anyone know where that is?

*Does anyone know if there is a command to restore a window, if not where is the code for the window button?*

EDIT1: my specific question really is to find a shell command to use in a keyboard shortcut that I can map to a mouse gesture, to be the opposite of a maximize gesture. It would also be helpful to know if there is a command for 'restore from minimized' because there is one for Windows, without using a user script to cycle through the z order of windows. This could help to find the command for the Restore button.

Comment: This question probably belongs on meta.askubuntu.com , but I don't think *mods* unmark an answer as accepted, the OP (*original poster*) can I believe change their mind and select a better answer for them.  (*Sorry I have almost no experience asking questions here*)

Comment: @guiverc, sorry, posted the wrong link about the incorrect marking.. updated.. it is from meta

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I feel there's too much background and not enough actual "question" in your question. For example, we don't know your distro, its version, your desktop environment, or the window manager in use. You mention gestures without any specifics. I think your question would benefit from a rewrite as well as from additional information. *Don't focus too much on it being a duplicate of another question with a possibly incorrectly accepted answer*. That can be litigated in meta 

Comment: Follow-up on the removed answer: I am afraid you are missing the point on what is programmatically needed. "I challenge you claim there is no simple call, because the OS is doing something with the Restore button" - What do you think the button runs?  And no, (0) is not the first window, it is the timestamp argument Wnck needs. I am afraid I can't give you what you are looking for. Removing the answer.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, no need to remove your answer.. (Ill post it below, as it may be useful for others). Actually, I may post it in the other question, as it would really be the correct answer there. Maybe you want to do that? Ill wait a bit to see..

Comment: It is obviously not the answer you are looking for, and not an answer on the changed question, and please don't post it as an answer anywhere. You cannot post someone else's answer.

Comment: Well, I am asking before I change someones work (although I will assume good intentions for your edits to my title). And technically, if its not posted, I dont think that applies. . but seriously, why wouldnt you want to help the other person on their question?  I think transparency and good will prevails here.. meaning more important than you or I.

Comment: Again, don't post it. Let' s not discuss.

Comment: Well, I suppose Ill have to ask the mods what to do in this case, if you are closing discussion about it. sheesh

Comment: Finally - to be honest, no clue what you are actually asking anymore. It doesn't make any sense, it's a mess. Bottom line is the answer is not a match -apparently- to what you are trying to ask. What I do with the answer then is irrelevant to you, and you definitely don' t have my permission to post it as an answer to another question. It's simply none of your business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple years, I asked on KDE Forum (will post link) and someone noted that using the same keyboard shortcut to maximize will restore the window!

https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=174425&hilit=maximize+restore