# Grouping application windows in an arranged setup

Tags: unity, workspace-switcher, layout, launcher

Is there any application or ways to group multiple open windows together so that they open together in layout it is arranged.

For example, If I arrange these application like this then on any icon of these application in Ubuntu launcher, it opens as it is arranged.

```
---------------------------------------------
|      Gedit           |   Gnome Terminal   |
|                      |                    |
|                      |                    |
|                      |                    |
|                      |                    |
|                      |                    |
|                      |--------------------|
|                      |   Google Chrome    |
|                      |                    |
|                      |                    |
|                      |                    |
|                      |                    |
|                      |                    |
|                      |                    |
---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I would set the option as a right-click quicklist option in the application's launcher. Leave a comment if you need any help with that. You can even create one command to open three application windows in a pre- defined arrangement, simply by using `&&` between the separate commands in the link.

Comment: Another thing you might find useful: http://askubuntu.com/a/645614/72216